# Writing a shorter form of the if statements in this useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to write the if statements in this code less repetitive? How do I make it shorter?

```
  useEffect(() => {
   function addDefaultCards() {
     Object.entries(allCurrencies).map((item) => {
      if (item[0] === "EUR") {
        setCards((prevItems) => [...prevItems, item]);
      }

      if (item[0] === "USD") {
        setCards((prevItems) => [...prevItems, item]);
      }

      if (item[0] === "RUB") {
        setCards((prevItems) => [...prevItems, item]);
      }

      if (item[0] === "INR") {
        setCards((prevItems) => [...prevItems, item]);
      }
   });
  return cards;
}
addDefaultCards();
}, [allCurrencies]);
```

Comment: I don't understand why there are lot's of if statements here? what are they doing? They all doing the same thing!

Comment: `if (['RUB', 'INR', 'USD', 'EUR'].contains(item[0]) { setCards(...)}`

as a note: your function `addDefaultCards` isn't called anywhere. Call it or remove function wrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just need an array of currencies to check for inclusion.

```
const currencies = ['EUR', 'USD', 'RUB', 'INR'];
useEffect(() => {
    Object.entries(allCurrencies).forEach((entry) => {
        if (currencies.includes(entry[0])) {
            setCards((prevItems) => [...prevItems, entry]);
        }
    });
}, [allCurrencies]);
```

You do not need the extra nested `addDefaultCards` function, and you should only use `.map` when constructing a new array one-to-one by returning from the `.map` callback (which you aren't doing). For side-effects, use `forEach` or a for loop. You also don't need `return cards`, since nothing uses `addDefaultCards`'s return value.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to filter the array then call `setCards`:

```
useEffect(() => {
   function addDefaultCards() {
     const items = Object.entries(allCurrencies).filter((item) => {
      return ["EUR", "USD", "RUB", "INR"].includes(item[0]);
     });
     setCards((prevItems) => [...prevItems, ...items]);
   }
   addDefaultCards();
}, [allCurrencies])
```

You can also do it without a wrapper function:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const items = Object.entries(allCurrencies).filter((item) => {
     return ["EUR", "USD", "RUB", "INR"].includes(item[0]);
   });
   setCards((prevItems) => [...prevItems, ...items]);
}, [allCurrencies])
```